# get current user to use it in the save method for one of my models

Tags: django, django-models

I need to get the current user logged in the save method for one of my models, just like the `request.user` from the views but in the save model method, is this posible? and if it is, how can I do it?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

if you have model like this in your models.py:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(User, editable=False)
```

Then in your admin.py it should be:

```
class PostAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
        if not change:
            obj.created_by = request.user
        obj.save()
admin.site.register(Post, PostAdmin);
```

You can also remove the `editable=False` if you want to allow the user to assign the `created_by` to another user.

Comment: Thanks, it was helpful for me, you can add the readonly_fields attribute in the example.