# Django Models Clean Method for Admin and Staff User

Tags: django

I have a task and i need to write a solution to this problem.

Have 2 fields parking_on and parking_off. If the user is staffuser then parking_off date has to be the same as parking_on and if the user is admin, then parking_off can be on a different date than parking_on.

```
class Parking(models.Model):
parking_on = models.DateField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False, blank=True, null=True,
                                  help_text='Alege data cand doresti sa vii in office',)
parking_off = models.DateField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False, blank=True, null=True,
                                   help_text='Alege Data Plecarii')
```

Have tried with this, but it doesn't catch the error, it simply save to the database:

```
def clean_parking_off(self, request):
    if not request.user.is_superuser and self.parking_off !=self.parking_on:
        raise ValidationError(
            {'parking_off': _('You cant book for a future date!')})
```

and i have this saving function:

```
def save(self):
    list = []
    d = self.parking_on
    while d <= self.parking_off:
        list.append(
            Parking(user=self.user,
                    email=self.email,
                    parking_on=d,
                    parking_off=d,
                    location=self.location
                    )
        )
        d = d + timedelta(days=1)
    Parking.objects.bulk_create(list)
```

Answer (score 0):

as the [Django Document](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.clean) says:

> Note, however, that like Model.full_clean(), a model’s clean() method is not invoked when you call your model’s save() method.

so same happen to your `clean_parking_off` method. you must call it in save method that will need to pass `request` to save method too, witch is not a good way.

you can see this problem from another side, if you are using admin panel this validation can be done by overriding `save_model` as you can see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35096342/get-current-user-to-use-it-in-the-save-method-for-one-of-my-models/35099791) and in views you have access to `request.user` too.

Comment: I am using only django admin. This is a simple apple...without views etc

Comment: Hi @Cohen, so as i said above, overriding `save_model` method would work for you, this way you don't need to override model `save` method and even have a `clean_parking_off` method.

Comment: i did as you told me and still, it doesnt do what is required.

Comment: def save_model_clean(self, request, obj, form, change):
        if not request.user.is_superuser:
            if self.parking_off != self.parking_on:
                raise ValidationError(
                    {'parking_off': _('You cant book for a future date!')})
            obj.save()

Comment: you must put this method in model AdminClass, and also it must be named `save_model`. try this and let me know if it works :)

Answer (score -1):

It worked with this:

```
ASA SE FILTREAZA ELEMENTE IN FUNCTIE DE user
def remove_from_fieldsets(fieldsets, fields):
        for fieldset in fieldsets:
            for field in fields:
                if field in fieldset[1]['fields']:
                    new_fields = []
                    for new_field in fieldset[1]['fields']:
                        if not new_field in fields:
                            new_fields.append(new_field)

                    fieldset[1]['fields'] = tuple(new_fields)
                    break
   def get_fieldsets(self, request, obj=None):
       fieldsets = super(ParkingModelAdmin, self).get_fieldsets(request, obj)

    if not request.user.is_superuser:
        remove_from_fieldsets(fieldsets, ('parking_off',))

    return fieldsets
```